# Achieving the "opposite" of a pivot table - reshaping table to make the unique value of a selected column the index

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

What I'm trying to achieve is kind of the reverse of a pivot_table.

Basically, I'm starting with this Dataframe:

[image: starting df]

The code to generate this is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'bus ticket type':['student', 'student', 'student', 'senior', 'senior', 'senior'],
                         'distance (km)':['5', '10', '15', '5', '10', '15'],
                         'bus fare':['100', '120', '130', '90', '100', '110']})
```

You see how there's 3 unique values in `'distance (km)'`, 5, 10, and 15km? I'm trying to make the unique values in this column the index of the dataframe.

So I want to transform it into:

[image: df2]

The code to generate the 2nd dataframe is:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'distance (km)':['5', '10', '15'],
                             'student_bus_fare':['100', '120', '130'],
                            'senior_bus_fare':['90', '100', '110']})
```

I'm not trying to calculate the mean or sum scores for either the 'students' or 'seniors' category, nor am i trying to achieve some kind of similar `aggfunc` usage based on distance.

I purely want to re-shape it so that unique values in `distance` are the index. All the original values representing fares are still in-tact.

Comment: This isn't a "reverse" pivot, it's just a pivot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `.pivot`

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'bus ticket type':['student', 'student', 'student', 'senior', 'senior', 'senior'],
                         'distance (km)':['5', '10', '15', '5', '10', '15'],
                         'bus fare':['100', '120', '130', '90', '100', '110']})

df2 = df.pivot(index='distance (km)', columns='bus ticket type', values='bus fare')
```

yields

```
bus ticket type senior student
distance (km)                 
10                 100     120
15                 110     130
5                   90     100
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I see how this is like the key-value pairs in R. Is there a way to tweak it so that the column names don't appear as belonging to a hierarchy under "bus ticket type". Basically so it sticks by the single row and single column conventions.

Comment: @Yeahprettymuch If you run `df2.info()` and `df2.columns`, you'll see that the column names are just `'senior'` and `'student'`; `'bus ticket type'` is the name of the columns. You can proceed with referring to `df2['senior']` without issue. Or, if desired, you can use `df2.columns.name` to reassign the column name to `None`.

Comment: Thank you again, that was crystal clear. Upon applying `df3.columns.name = None` and `df3 = df3.reset_index()` I got EXACTLY the dataframe I was trying to achieve. You're awesome!!

Comment: @Yeahprettymuch Glad it helped. Cheers